# combining results of two select statements

Tags: sql, t-sql, select

I'm using T-SQL with ASP.NET, and c# and i'm pretty new to SQL.

I was wondering how i could combine the results of two queries

**Query1:**

```
SELECT tableA.Id,  tableA.Name, [tableB].Username AS Owner, [tableB].ImageUrl, [tableB].CompanyImageUrl, COUNT(tableD.UserId) AS NumberOfUsers
 FROM tableD RIGHT OUTER JOIN 
         [tableB] INNER JOIN
         tableA ON [tableB].Id = tableA.Owner ON tableD.tableAId = tableA.Id
 GROUP BY tableA.Name, [tableB].Username, [tableB].ImageUrl, [tableB].CompanyImageUrl
```

**Query2:**

```
 SELECT tableA.Id,  tableA.Name, COUNT([tableC].Id) AS NumberOfPlans
 FROM   [tableC] RIGHT OUTER JOIN
           tableA ON [tableC].tableAId = tableA.Id
 GROUP BY tableA.Id, tableA.Name
```

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Comment: ...why do you want to combine them?

Comment: You want to do something with two queries, but impossible to guess what; 'combine' is much to vague.

Comment: Your first query should give an error: `Column 'tableA.Id' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.`

Comment: Please describe what you want to achieve. For example, what would the result look like in terms of the data you get out. What are the reasons for putting the two queries together?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

**You can use a [Union](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180026.aspx).**

This will return the results of the queries in separate rows.

First you must make sure that both queries return identical columns.

Then you can do :

```
SELECT tableA.Id, tableA.Name, [tableB].Username AS Owner, [tableB].ImageUrl, [tableB].CompanyImageUrl, COUNT(tableD.UserId) AS Number
FROM tableD 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN [tableB] 
INNER JOIN tableA ON [tableB].Id = tableA.Owner ON tableD.tableAId = tableA.Id 
GROUP BY tableA.Name, [tableB].Username, [tableB].ImageUrl, [tableB].CompanyImageUrl

UNION

SELECT tableA.Id, tableA.Name,  '' AS Owner, '' AS ImageUrl, '' AS CompanyImageUrl, COUNT([tableC].Id) AS Number
FROM 
[tableC] 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN tableA ON [tableC].tableAId = tableA.Id GROUP BY tableA.Id, tableA.Name
```

As has been mentioned, both queries return quite different data. You would probably only want to do this if both queries return data that could be considered similar.

SO

**You can use a Join**

If there is some data that is shared between the two queries. This will put the results of both queries into a single row joined by the id, which is probably more what you want to be doing here...

You could do :

```
SELECT tableA.Id, tableA.Name, [tableB].Username AS Owner, [tableB].ImageUrl, [tableB].CompanyImageUrl, COUNT(tableD.UserId) AS NumberOfUsers, query2.NumberOfPlans
FROM tableD 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN [tableB] 
INNER JOIN tableA ON [tableB].Id = tableA.Owner ON tableD.tableAId = tableA.Id 


INNER JOIN 
  (SELECT tableA.Id, COUNT([tableC].Id) AS NumberOfPlans 
   FROM [tableC] 
   RIGHT OUTER JOIN tableA ON [tableC].tableAId = tableA.Id 
   GROUP BY tableA.Id, tableA.Name) AS query2 
ON query2.Id = tableA.Id

GROUP BY tableA.Name, [tableB].Username, [tableB].ImageUrl, [tableB].CompanyImageUrl
```

Answer (score 6):

While it is possible to combine the results, I would advise against doing so.

You have two fundamentally different types of queries that return a different number of rows, a different number of columns and different types of data. It would be best to leave it as it is - two separate queries.

Comment: its for a stored procedure which will return a single table in JSON (only want to make one ajax call).
There will not be a different number of rows and tableA.ID, and tableA.Name are in both queries.

Comment: @ErnieStings: It is possible to make a JSON call without having to put all your data into a single result set. Your current strategy will pass duplicated data if a user is owner for multiple tableA.

Answer (score 6):

Probably you use Microsoft SQL Server which support Common Table Expressions (CTE) (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766.aspx) which are very friendly for query optimization. So I suggest you my favor construction:

```
WITH GetNumberOfPlans(Id,NumberOfPlans) AS (
    SELECT tableA.Id, COUNT(tableC.Id)
    FROM tableC
        RIGHT OUTER JOIN tableA ON tableC.tableAId = tableA.Id
    GROUP BY tableA.Id
),GetUserInformation(Id,Name,Owner,ImageUrl,
                     CompanyImageUrl,NumberOfUsers) AS (
    SELECT tableA.Id, tableA.Name, tableB.Username AS Owner, tableB.ImageUrl,
        tableB.CompanyImageUrl,COUNT(tableD.UserId),p.NumberOfPlans
    FROM tableA
        INNER JOIN tableB ON tableB.Id = tableA.Owner
        RIGHT OUTER JOIN tableD ON tableD.tableAId = tableA.Id
    GROUP BY tableA.Name, tableB.Username, tableB.ImageUrl, tableB.CompanyImageUrl
)
SELECT u.Id,u.Name,u.Owner,u.ImageUrl,u.CompanyImageUrl
    ,u.NumberOfUsers,p.NumberOfPlans
FROM GetUserInformation AS u
    INNER JOIN GetNumberOfPlans AS p ON p.Id=u.Id
```

After some experiences with CTE you will be find very easy to write code using CTE and you will be happy with the performance.

Comment: This will probably give the same error as the original query.

Comment: @Mark Byers: No, it **must** work without an error (I take not in consideration writing errors which I could made)! I am only not sure whether one should use INNER JOIN or an OUTER JOIN or UNION to combine GetUserInformation with GetNumberOfPlans. CTE works like a VIEWs or temporary tables, but much more effective. If you save the results of the first query in a temporary table and the results of the second query in the second table you will be able to JOIN the tables. CTE makes this, but SQL use already existing indexes on existing tables.

Comment: @Mark Byers: To be absolutely sure one can combine tableA with GetUserInformation and GetNumberOfPlans with respect of OUTER JOIN on both subqueries. This will give the most full result set