# How can I join this 2 queries?(A select query with join and An unpivot query)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, unpivot

Here are my two queries

```
SELECT EWND.Position,
NKey = CASE WHEN ISNULL(Translation.Name, '') = '' THEN EWND.Name
ELSE  Translation.Name END, Unit = EW_N_DEF.Units                               
FROM EWND
INNER JOIN EW_N_DEF ON EW_N_DEF.Nutr_No = EWND.Nutr_No
LEFT JOIN Translation ON Translation.CodeMain = EWND.Nutr_no
WHERE Translation.CodeTrans  = 1
ORDER BY EWND.Position
```

And this is the unpivot one

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
   (SELECT N1,N2,N3,N4,N5,N6,N7,N8,N9,N10,N11,N12,N13,N14,N15,N16,N17,N18,N19,N20,N21,N22,N23,N24,N25,N26,N27,N28,N29,N30,N31,N32,N33,N34
   FROM EWNVal WHERE Code=6035) Test
UNPIVOT
   (Value FOR NUTCODE IN 
      (N1,N2,N3,N4,N5,N6,N7,N8,N9,N10,N11,N12,N13,N14,N15,N16,N17,N18,N19,N20,N21,N22,N23,N24,N25,N26,N27,N28,N29,N30,N31,N32,N33,N34)
)AS test
```

The output of the queries are like this:

```
  Position Name         Unit
    1   Calories    
    2   Protein g
    3   Total Fat           g
    4   Total Carbs         g
    5   Calories from Fat   
    6   Saturated Fat       g
    7   Trans Fat           g
    8   Monounsaturated Fat g
    9   Polyunsaturated Fat g
```

And

```
Value Code
    0   N1
    0   N2
    0   N3
    0   N4
    0   N5
    0   N6
    0   N7
    0   N8
    0   N9
```

The output must be like this

```
1   Calories                0   N1
2   Protein             g   0   N2
3   Total Fat           g   0   N3
4   Total Carbs         g   0   N4
5   Calories from Fat       0   N5
6   Saturated Fat       g   0   N6
7   Trans Fat           g   0   N7
8   Monounsaturated Fat g   0   N8
9   Polyunsaturated Fat g   0   N9
```

Both Queries put out same number of rows but not columns, Is it possible to join this two? I tried the union but it has problems that I cant solve

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can provide sample data with desired results?

Comment: @MANGKANOR Do the two record sets relate to each other in any way?

Comment: I guess so, it is joined based on its CODE, N1 for position 1 and so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your data from the two queries is joinable based on the numeric portion of the `Code` and `Position` then you might be able to use something like this:

```
select q1.position,
  q1.name,
  q2.value,
  q2.code
from
(
  SELECT EWND.Position,
    NKey = CASE WHEN ISNULL(Translation.Name, '') = '' THEN EWND.Name
                ELSE  Translation.Name END, Unit = EW_N_DEF.Units                               
  FROM EWND
  INNER JOIN EW_N_DEF 
    ON EW_N_DEF.Nutr_No = EWND.Nutr_No
  LEFT JOIN Translation 
    ON Translation.CodeMain = EWND.Nutr_no
  WHERE Translation.CodeTrans  = 1
) q1
full outer join
(
  SELECT value, code
  FROM 
  (
     SELECT N1,N2,N3,N4,N5,N6,N7,N8,N9,N10,N11,N12,N13,N14,N15,N16,N17,N18,N19,N20,N21,N22,N23,N24,N25,N26,N27,N28,N29,N30,N31,N32,N33,N34
     FROM EWNVal 
     WHERE Code=6035
  ) Test
  UNPIVOT
  (
    Value FOR NUTCODE IN 
        (N1,N2,N3,N4,N5,N6,N7,N8,N9,N10,N11,N12,N13,N14,N15,N16,N17,N18,N19,N20,N21,N22,N23,N24,N25,N26,N27,N28,N29,N30,N31,N32,N33,N34)
  )AS test
) q2
  on q1.Position = right(q1.code, len(q1.code)-1)
```

Comment: Thank you so much bluefeet! This worked, I just changed the q1.name into q1.Nkey and other column names. But this is the thing I was looking for! thanks a lot ^_ __^

Answer (score 0):

In Union and Union all you must have both the result have same column name. for column you can use any alias for that but column name must be same.

for that you can refer this answer

[combining results of two select statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2826627/combining-results-of-two-select-statements)