# How can I combine results from two SQL queries?

Tags: sql, .net

How can I combine results from two SQL queries?

**First Query:**

```
Select T.NUM1,T.AM1
FROM
(
    Select Number AS NUM1,SUM(AMOUNT) As AM1 FROM TBLSALES WHERE NUMBER<20 GROUP BY NUMBER
)T
```

**Second Query**

```
SELECT B.NUM2,B.AM2
FROM
(
    SELECT Number AS NUM2,SUM(AMOUNT) As AM2 FROM TBLSALES WHERE NUMBER>19 AND NUMBER<40 GROUP BY NUMBER
)B
```

Comment: Use `UNION` clause

Comment: see example here https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp

Comment: Possible duplicate of [combining results of two select statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2826627/combining-results-of-two-select-statements)

Comment: Alias Column names with empty string on both queries,`union all` and  you will get 4 columns in output

Answer (score 1):

The UNION or UNION ALL should work as long as the numbers of columns and types are the same.

```
Select T.NUM1 as NUM,T.AM1 as AM
FROM
(
    Select Number AS NUM1,SUM(AMOUNT) As AM1 FROM TBLSALES WHERE NUMBER<20 GROUP BY NUMBER
)T

UNION

SELECT B.NUM2 as NUM,B.AM2 as AM
FROM
(
    SELECT Number AS NUM2,SUM(AMOUNT) As AM2 FROM TBLSALES WHERE NUMBER>19 AND NUMBER<40 GROUP BY NUMBER
)B
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use UNION to merge query results.
If you want to avoid duplicate records, you should use UNION and if you don't want to exclude duplicate results, use UNION ALL in that case.